# How to calculate Transit Time per Application Id?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the below

```
public class ApplicationStatusModel
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationStatus { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which is populated with some records as

```
List<ApplicationStatusModel> objApplicationStatusModel = new List<ApplicationStatusModel>();

objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 1, ApplicationStatus = "Status1", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 12, 30, 10) });

objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 1, ApplicationStatus = "Status2", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 13, 30, 40) });

objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status1", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 14, 12, 08) });

objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status2", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 15, 30, 10) });

objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status3", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 15, 40, 34) });
```

I am looking for the **Transit Time per Application Id**  like

[image]

Below is the way to calculate it

***// Hours calculation for Status1 = time to transit from Status1 to Status2***

***// Hours calculation Status2 = time to transit from Status2 to Status3***

e.g.

*For Application Id = 1, Status 1,  it is 24/04/2020 13:30:40 - 24/04/2020 12:30:10 = 1 hour : 30 seconds*

*For Application Id = 2, Status 1 it is 24/04/2020 15:30:10 - 24/04/2020 14:12:08 = 1 hour : 18 minutes : 2 seconds*

*For Application Id = 2, Status 2 it is 24/04/2020 15:40:34 - 24/04/2020 15:30:10 = 10 minutes : 24 seconds*

The DTO is as under

```
public class TransitReportModel
{
    #region

    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string TransitTime { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the source list by `ApplicationId` property, then iterate groups, calculate the required time and add items to result list

```cs
var grouped = objApplicationStatusModel
    .GroupBy(s => s.ApplicationId);

var result = new List<TransitReportModel>();
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < group.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        var time = group.ElementAt(i + 1).CreatedDate - group.ElementAt(i).CreatedDate;
        result.Add(new TransitReportModel
        {
            ApplicationId = group.Key, StatusName = group.ElementAt(i).ApplicationStatus,
            TransitTime = time.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

Using a loops here is more clear and readable, rather the adding a nested Linq methods, IMO

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some kind of this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ApplicationStatusModel> objApplicationStatusModel = new List<ApplicationStatusModel>();

        objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 1, ApplicationStatus = "Status1", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 12, 30, 10) });

        objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 1, ApplicationStatus = "Status2", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 13, 30, 40) });

        objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status1", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 14, 12, 08) });

        objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status2", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 15, 30, 10) });

        objApplicationStatusModel.Add(new ApplicationStatusModel { ApplicationId = 2, ApplicationStatus = "Status3", CreatedDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 20, 15, 40, 34) });


        var List = objApplicationStatusModel
            .Select(x => new { cur = x, next = objApplicationStatusModel.ElementAtOrDefault(objApplicationStatusModel.IndexOf(x) + 1) })
            .Where(x => x.cur.ApplicationId == x.next?.ApplicationId)
            .Select(x=> new TransitReportModel() {
                ApplicationId = x.cur.ApplicationId,
                StatusName = x.cur.ApplicationStatus,
                TransitTime = (x.next.CreatedDate - x.cur.CreatedDate).ToString()
            });
    }


    public class ApplicationStatusModel
    {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationStatus { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransitReportModel
    {
        #region

        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public string TransitTime { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```